# Align to center image in bootstrap carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

This is what I have:
[image]

I want to make each image appear in the centre of the carousel. This is my javascript code I decided to implement:

```
$('.carousel-inner img').each(function(){
    // image dimensions
    var w = $(this).width();

    //get parent dimensions
    var div_w =$(".carousel-inner").width();

    //set img position
    this.style.left = div_w / 2 - w / 2 + 'px';
});
```

This code should adjust the left margin for each image according to their width. The problem is that this code will apply the left margin from first image for each image from each slide; instead, it should calculate for each image the margin separately.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `.active` class appear to be assigned to parent element of image being displayed

Try

```
if ($(this).parent("div.item").is(".active")) {
  this.style.left = div_w / 2 - w / 2 + 'px';
}
```